# Resonant frequency of copper tape

Tags: antenna, radio

I understand that if I want a piece of wire to act as an antenna the length of the wire should be at least λ/4.

I wanted to know what would be the equivalent if I used a piece of copper tape instead of a wire.

Comment: It's the same - assuming the tape's width and the wire's thickness are much smaller than the wavelength.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wire ribbon as antenna would be equivalent to a "fat" wire of increased diameter. For a ribbon to be resonant, it should be slightly shorter in length than a thin wire.
 For example, a resonant half-wave thin wire having length/diameter ratio of 1000 should be about 97.2% long compared to half-wavelength (*taken from Chapt2 graph Fig.3 of **The ARRL Antenna Book, 1982** 14th edition):

- length/diameter 3000: 97.7%
- length/diameter 1000: 97.2%
- length/diameter 500: 97.0%
- length/diameter 200: 96.7%
- length/diameter 100: 96.3%
- length/diameter 50: 95.7%
- length/diameter 20: 94.4%
- length/diameter 10: 92.5%

In addition, a ribbon has a lower Q (wider bandwidth) and a lower radiation resistance at resonance than a thin wire. All these points assume the the wire or ribbon sits in free space, well away from other objects and that its ratio is constant throughout its length.

*Copper tape* suggests that it might be attached to something, rather than free-space described above. Even a non-conducting attachment alters resonant frequency due to its dielectric constant.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. Your explanation makes complete sense. I made a dipole out of the copper tape and the length of the antenna required was lesser then what I calculated. Also thanks for the recommendation as well.